# How to use condition after UNWIND in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have this cypher query

```
WITH ["first", "second"] AS things, -1 AS index
UNWIND range(0,size(things)-1) AS i  
Return things[i]
```

Now I wanna check if there is `things[i]` where it does equal "first" then return the index of it, in this case 0 where "first" has the index 0. But I have no idea how to write the condition after the UNWIND.

I tried to add the condition after return like this:

```
WITH ["first", "second"] AS things, -1 AS index
UNWIND range(0,size(things)-1) AS i  
Return CASE WHEN things[i] = "first" THEN i AS index
```

But it doesn't work, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one **"first"** in this list but there may be more than one occurrences of "first" in the list.

I am sharing here Cypher to get the **first index of any string in the list(here "first")**.

```
WITH ["first", "second"] AS things, -1 AS index
RETURN [x IN range(0,size(things)-1) WHERE things[x] = "second"][0] AS index
```

.

**EDIT**: Above Cypher returns **null** if no string found in the list.
If you want -1 or any other value in case string not found, use the following query:

```
WITH ["first", "second"] AS things, -1 AS index
WITH [x IN range(0,size(things)-1) WHERE things[x] = "first"][0] AS index
RETURN  CASE WHEN index IS NOT NULL THEN index ELSE -1 END AS index
```

Comment: You can also use `apoc.coll.indexOf(coll, value)` using APOC Procedures to get the index of an item in a collection